# Replacing the default String class with a custom class in Java

Tags: java, string, standard-library

I would like to implement my own String class and get Java to use it when I am using double quotes.
It should look like that: `MyString s = "foo"` and the java.lang.String should not be instantiated.

Is that possible without touching the compiler?
How would it be done?

The reason I am asking is that I need strings in a program that needs to be verified for worst case execution time. In order to verify it, all loops must be bounded (the bound is specified in a comment).
Furthermore, I would like to be able to use double quote for convenience, because writing `MyString s = new MyString({'f','o','o'})` really decrease readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible whitout touching the compiler.

It is even not possible to subclass String. (You can only provice your own Implementation of `java.lang.ChareSequence`, but this will not help a lot.)

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the String class. Take the source for String, change it keeping all the method signatures the same, compile it and add it to your bootclasspath. Note: this will replace all Strings, not just those in your code. It may also not compily with your usage license. ;)

If you are worried about readability you can create a helper method which does

```
MyString s = s("Hello");
```

If all you want to do is slow down your application you can do a number of things like;

- use the slowest machine you can find. There are plenty of cheap ones on ebay.
- disable the JIT.
- enable debugging.
- enable profiling and track every method calls and object creation.

Comment: This will actually instanciate a "Hello" String and pass it to the s method, which is probably not hitting the nail on the head...

Comment: "Hello" is a literal so is not created dynamically.  The OP did want a "worst case execution time" ;) A very slightly tuned worst case execution time doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I actually want to be able to calculate the worst case execution time. I just need to place a bound on loops (and that will limit the length of the string but that's an other matter). I am quite sure String has methods that uses loops (equals fx.). But I'll look at your solution using the bootclasspath.

Answer (score 2):

You can look for really complicated solutions, like modifying your bytecode at runtime to use MyString everywhere you use String, using a framework like ASM, for example, but good luck with that!

http://asm.ow2.org/

It's probably a better idea to try to get the same result by another way...

Comment: And, yes, your MyString class should definitively implement java.lang.CharSequence

Answer (score 2):

Stringer literals are only instantiated once, so don't worry about cost of time.

```
MyString s = new MyString("foo")
```

That is fine for your purpose. Only one `String` instance of `"foo"` is ever created. (Even if multiple source files contain the `"foo"` literal). It's almost as if

```
static private final String $foo = JVM.findOrCreateString('f','o','o');
...
MyString s = new MyString($foo);
```